# Haml + ActionMailer - Rails?

Tags: ruby, haml, actionmailer

I'm trying to use ActionMailer without Rails in a project, and I want to use Haml for the HTML email templates.  Anyone have any luck getting this configured and initialized so that the templates will be found and rendered?  I'm currently getting errors like:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template new_reg/daily_stats/full with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en]} in view paths "/home/petersen/new_reg/lib/new_reg/mailers/views"
```

To clarify, this is ActionMailer 3.0.4

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Comment: Could you share your ActionMailer code? On [ActionMailer API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) it says:  "Like Action Controller, each mailer class has a corresponding view directory in which each method of the class looks for a template with its name. To define a template to be used with a mailing, create an .erb file with the same name as the method in your mailer model."

Comment: @jschulenklopper: I've already managed to configure ActionMailer to look into a useful directory for views, it's just not enabling Haml or looking for the .haml extension.  All I have is a 
    `require "haml"`
line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the issue is that without the full Rails stack, Haml doesn't completely load, specifically the Haml::Plugin class.  Adding `require 'haml/template/plugin'` after the normal `require 'haml'` line seems to solve the problems.

Comment: For future googlers whom might have the same problem as me (uninitialized constant Haml::Template), be sure to include `require 'haml/template/options'` as well.

Answer (score 1):

`require 'haml/template/plugin'` in the "configure do" block together with `ActionMailer::Base.view_paths = "./views/"` did it for me (Sinatra)

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary in Rails -- but since you're using ActionMailer without Rails -- did you specify `ActionMailer::Base.register_template_extension('haml')`?

Comment: as @Joseph mentioned, `ActionMailer::Base.register_template_extension('haml')` doesn't exist in ActionMailer 3+.

Comment: @dunedain289, Yes, I see that as well now. Well... it used to be a solution. Sorry for the confusion in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a similar issue and am using ActionMailer 3.0.3. register_template_extension does not exist in ActionMailer 3.

I'm using Sinatra. I've got mailer.rb (below) in APP_ROOT/lib and the views are located in APP_ROOT/views/mailer. This sends an email with a subject, the body is blank though.

```
require 'action_mailer'
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.view_paths = File.dirname(__FILE__)+"/../views/"
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'exmaple.com',
  :user_name            => 'user@exmaple.com',
  :password             => 'password',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }

class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base

   def new_comment_notifier(post,comment)
      @post = post
      @comment = comment

      mail(:to => "user@example.com",
           :subject => "new comment on: #{post.title}")
   end
end
```

Comment: there may be an issue with [Rails 3](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5078-actionmailer-does-not-support-haml)